# Retrieve value of dynamic generated textarea in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, dom-traversal

```
<div id="post">
  <form name="postComment" id="commentPost6" action="javascript:void(0);" method="post"
    target="_top" onsubmit="return commentPost(6)">
     <textarea name="comment" id="comment6" class="commentText" 
        cols="10" rows="3" accesskey="1">
     </textarea><br>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" id="commentpost" value="Submit" accesskey="2">
  </form>
</div>
```

this is my **post** div tag, i have **multiple div** tag with same id="post", 
the form and fields are dynamically generated and id of both **form** and **textarea** are unique, so that there is no problem in retriving those values, on click of submit, i call **commentPost** method.

```
function commentPost(postId)
{
    alert("Inside commentpost");
    //how to retrive/access value of textarea here

}
```

how to get value of textarea ??
and just in case

Yes, i know it's not valid HTML to have multiple elements with the same ID.

Comment: Yes, you know it's not valid. Yes, you still don't understand why everyone says you should write valid HTML. Use classes instead.

Comment: okay, bažmegakapa if i use classes, then how would i retrieve values cause i tried using classes and it did not worked out good for me, so tell me, if i am wrong and exactly where i am

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#comment'+postId).val();
```

Why aren't you simply using classes instead of ids? (post)

Answer (score 1):

```
function commentPost(postId)
{
    alert("Inside commentpost");
    aler($("#commentPost"+postId).find('textarea').val());

}
```

This will give you the textarea value

Answer (score 1):

**Revised HTML** (`post` is now a class, `javascript:` removed from `action`):

```
<div class="post">
  <form name="postComment" id="commentPost6" action="" method="post"
    target="_top" onsubmit="return commentPost(this)">
     <textarea name="comment" id="comment6" class="commentText" 
        cols="10" rows="3" accesskey="1">
     </textarea><br>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" id="commentpost" value="Submit" accesskey="2">
  </form>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function commentPost(form)
{
    var textAreaValue = $(form).find('.commentText').val();
    console.log(textAreaValue);
}
```

---

Even better, you should start writing **advanced event handlers** instead of these inline ones (`onsubmit=""` and friends). jQuery provides [great methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/) for this.

```
$('.post form').submit(function (e) {
    var textAreaValue = $(this).find('.commentText').val();
    console.log(textAreaValue);

    e.preventDefault(); //to prevent default event - which is form submission
});
```

Inline event handlers are good for quick tests, but they quickly lead to an unmaintainable, messy HTML source. You should follow the rule of [Separation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Depending if you pass the postId that matches your naming standard in that form like above you had 6.

```
function commentPost(postId) {
        alert("Inside commentpost");
        // One way.
        var $testAreaValue = $('textarea.commentText#comment' + postId).val();
        alert($testAreaValue);
        // second way.
        $testAreaValue = $('#comment' + postId).val();
        alert($testAreaValue);
}
```

Hope it helps.